# Dynamically allocating space causing error in MPI program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, mpi

There is an MPI program to calculate the product of two matrices here :
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kmkurn/39ca673bb37946055b38/raw/20ed8f7a7c078b82d12b9f7ef1390b9e9c67d626/mpi_mm.c

I used this exact code but instead of specifying the size of the matrix as a constant, I wanted to take them as input parameters. So I added the following code inside the main:

```
 int N = atoi(argv[1]);
    int M = atoi(argv[2]);

    double(*a)[M] = malloc(sizeof(double[N][M]));
    double(*b)[1] = malloc(sizeof(double[M][1]));
    double(*c)[1] = malloc(sizeof(double[N][1]));
    int NRA = N;
    int NCA = M;
    int NCB = 1;
```

compiled it with `mpicc` and ran with `mpiexec -n 4 ./a.out` and got the following error:

> ===================================================================================
> =   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
> =   PID 4960 RUNNING AT DESKTOP-NHT8PTC
> =   EXIT CODE: 11
> =   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
> =   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
> =================================================================================== YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault
> (signal 11) This typically refers to a problem with your application.
> Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions

What could be the reason for this? I am not sure what could be going wrong with just dynamic initialization of matrices.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: "ran with mpiexec -n 4 ./a.out" Don't you need to provide some command line arguments for your program in there so that you have something in argv[1] and argv[2] to access? [I.e. the pgmargs referred to here.](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www1/mpiexec.html)